# python pandas scatterplot error: is this a bug with pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Cant seem to get pandas to do a scatterplot:

Trying to do a scatterplot, keep getting this error:

```
 TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

basic example:

```
 x= self.df['he']
 y= self.df['xy']
 sct = plt.scatter(x,y)
```

I was trying to do a bubble plot (scatterplot with color and size), requires 4 additional args

bubble example:

```
color = self.df['clr'].values
size =  self.df['sze'].values
sct = plt.scatter(x, y, c=clr, s=size, linewidths=2, edgecolor='w')
```

again, regardless of simple (scatter) or complex (bubble): cannot get this beyond this error

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

any help is appreciated:
is this a bug in pandas? matplotlib throws error as well?
-best

Comment: Can you post some sample data so that this can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas 0.12` and `matplotlib 1.3` this should work, when you pass the columns of the `DataFrame` as arguments to scatter:

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 4), columns=list('abcd'))

In [19]: plt.scatter(df.a, df.b, c=df.c, s=df.d*100)
Out[19]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x380e050>
```

[image: pandas scatter example]

(So maybe you are using older versions or you are using "special" data).

For `pandas 0.13` there is an open pull request that will add "scatter" as an option to `df.plot` so that the following line should be equivalent:

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='b', c='c', s=df.d * 100)
```